# SQL Server: How to append a string to a value in a virtual column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a virtual column in a SQL Server query named `TempField`.

I would like each value in the virtual column to have the same value as the field1 column PLUS append a _suffix string (which is constant/same for all values).

Said another way, the XXX represents a string from field1 and _suffix is a string that I would like to append to XXX (the appended string is the same for all values).

```
SELECT field1, field2, 'XXX_suffix' as TempField
FROM table1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a table into the database?  What I would like is to do this 'on the fly', that's why I called it a "virtual" column because it would only be displayed in the query results but not stored anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I see. My apologies. I think both of you are already doing that, right?

Comment: @Charlie That is what Yashveers query does. My version adds a column that is calculated at query time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      declare @temp as table (FName varchar(100) , LName varchar(100),  Email varchar(100) )

            insert into @temp (FName,LName,Email) values ('A','B','C')
            insert into @temp (FName,LName,Email) values ('A1','B1','C1')
            insert into @temp (FName,LName,Email) values ('A2','B2','C2')
            insert into @temp (FName,LName,Email) values ('A','B','C')
            insert into @temp (FName,LName,Email) values ('A1','B1','C1')
            insert into @temp (FName,LName,Email) values ('A1','B1','C2')


            select FName,LName,Email, (FName +'_suffix') as NewColumn


            from @temp
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx), then this will do that for you:

```
create table test(
  column1 varchar(20),
  column2 as column1 + '_suffix' -- this is calculated when needed and not stored
);

insert test (column1) values ('adam'),('burt');

select * from test;

-- result:
column1  column2
-------  -----------
adam     adam_suffix
burt     burt_suffix
```

Comment: jpw, this works except that the   +  '_suffix' seems to be in the wrong location.  I only got it to work like this: column1 + '_suffix' as column2. It seems similar but the other way around gives an error.

Comment: @Charlie When doing a computed column AS should come before, but when making an alias for something at query-time, as in the other answer, AS should come after.

Comment: it was probably a terminology error on my part. What I needed was an alias then. Thanks for the clarification.